# Has the owner ignored the domain for 9 years?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar, whois

I'm interested in a domain that already has an owner.

I checked with Whois , and Whois reports that the domain has `Creation Date` and `Updated Date` of `5/15/2010`.

On the other hand, the `Registration Expiration Date` is `5/15/2019`.

Does this mean that the owner hasn't done anything with the domain for 9 years? Or is it possible that there's some type of automatic renewal that's not reflected in the "Creation Date" and "Updated Date"?

Comment: You are not stating at least the TLD so it is hard to give you meaningful answers. In gTLDs and many ccTLDs, renewals are done automatically by the registry around expiration date... until the registrar gives an explicit "delete" order. This does not count as an update on the domain, often.

Comment: I wouldn't think that it would be unusual to hold a domain for 9 years without doing much with it.   It could be planned for a future project that never seems to get off the ground, registered defensively in protection of a different trademark, or listed for sale at a price that nobody has been willing to pay.

Comment: The TLD is .com

Comment: Are we to assume that you have tried to access the DNS with your browser?

Comment: Yes. The browsers can’t connect to the server.

Comment: What do you mean by "browsers can't connect"? Are you seeing anything at all? Are you getting a 404message, or a placeholder message, or a blank page? Anything?

Answer (score 1):

`Updated Date` simply reflects the last time any information in the about the owner/admin/technical contact/... has changed.

`Expiration Date` is not part of this. Probably it is renewed yearly, and in 2-3 months the date will change to 2020

Comment: "Updated Date simply reflects the last time any information in the about the owner/admin/technical contact/..."  no, typically not only. If the contacts have changed OR if nameservers have changed OR if DNSSEC data has changed OR if domain statuses have changed OR if there has been a transfer. In general, because then you have specific rules per registry.